# what are .esm.js files and whats with the format: 'es' in rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I was just going through this library [HERE](https://github.com/glidejs/glide) (glide.js) , as i was checking the package.json file i see the following command under the key `scripts`:

```
 "build:esm": "rollup --config build/esm.js && rollup --config build/esm.modular.js",
```

What exactly is this script doing ? I know a a config file is being passed to rollup.js here, but whats with the `.esm` ? when i see the [dist/](https://github.com/glidejs/glide/tree/master/dist) folder i also see a `glide.esm.js` file , what exactly is this file doing ?

The build config file for esm looks like below:

```
import build from './build'

export default Object.assign(build, {
  input: 'entry/entry-complete.js',
  output: Object.assign(build.output, {
    file: 'dist/glide.esm.js',
    format: 'es'
  })
})
```

But i don't quite understand what the `format: 'es'` really means here. Basically to break it down , what is the difference between the `glide.js` and the `glide.esm.js` file in the `dist/` folder ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`format: 'es'` tells rollup that it should output the bundle in an ECMAScript Module aware way.  This means that it should create a bundle that can be `import`ed using something along the lines of:

```
import Glide from "some/place/glide/is/hosted/glide.js
```

If the context that this script is used in is not ESM aware, you will get syntax errors.  In that case, it makes more sense to use a UMD rollup bundle because it is the most compatible version of the bundle.

Explaining UMD in depth is beyond the scope of this question, but suffice it to say that it makes the bundle able to work with AMD and CommonJS aware loaders as well as populating a global namespace with the bundle's exports.

Additionally, for browsers that do not understand what ES modules are or would throw syntax errors if they tried to parse them, you can include a fallback script that would leverage the UMD or bundle of another format using a script of form: `<script src="some/non/esm/script.js" nomodule="true" />` which would tell an ESM aware context that it *shouldn't* run the linked script.

### Concrete Example

Consider the following snippet which *should* work in Firefox and Chrome since they support ESM modules.  Stack Overflow snippets do not have a way to load modules so you will need to put together a small project using the following code:

#### demo.js

```js
import Glide from "https://unpkg.com/@glidejs/glide@3.2.3/dist/glide.esm.js";

new Glide(".glide").mount();
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Module Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@glidejs/glide@3.2.3/dist/css/glide.core.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@glidejs/glide@3.2.3/dist/css/glide.theme.min.css" />
  <script type="module" src="demo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="glide">
      <div data-glide-el="track" class="glide__track">
        <ul class="glide__slides">
          <li class="glide__slide">Foo</li>
          <li class="glide__slide">Bar</li>
          <li class="glide__slide">Fizz</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so the code snippet you posted works in FF and chrome but would't work in other legacy browsers , i believe , theoretically speaking ..

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Correct, older browsers have no idea what `<script type="module"/>` means.  Please see [MDN's documentation on script elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element./script#attr-type).  Legacy browsers would ignore the script, since the `type` is neither omitted nor of JavaScript mime.  Please see my edit about using `nomodule="true"` to have a fallback script in such a case.

Comment: Thank you brotha !!

Comment: would you have any idea , how would you go about debugging a plugin written and split up in modules like this one here ::- https://github.com/glidejs/glide/tree/master/src ? if you can give me a general idea ... Thanks !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik The scripts will still behave like normal JS files; they will still appear in the "Scripts" tab of whatever browser you are using's developer console.  The difference is just how they are loaded in.  You may want to open your last comment as a new question and add as much detail as you can to it.  Describe what you think the issues are with trying to debug, how you tried to solve them, etc.  Answering something like that in the comments isn't really comment's purpose.

Comment: yes true , i should ask another question as thats a complex issue. Thanks alot for your help.TY ! :)