# ES6 dependency of loaded module not found (uncaught typeError) when initiating new instance

Tags: javascript, leaflet, es6-modules

I'm learning JS and due to my general lack of knowledge I don't seem to find the correct keywords to google the solution myself.

I am trying to load Leaflet as part of an app, built with ES6 modules.
File structure:

```
- Home directory
    - index.html
    - /scripts
         - main.js
         - /app
             - mapApp.js
         - /lib
             - leaflet.js
```

Inside index.html

```
    ...
    <script type="module" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    ...
```

mapApp contains an object, which will be extended to contain methods to alter the map/gui. In its most basic layout mapApp.js contains:

```
import * as L from "../lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"

function mapApp(container){

    // Fixed values
    var bounds = [
        [50.769562,5.448265], // Southwest coordinates
        [50.801687,5.507624] // Northeast coordinates
    ];

    // Parameters

    this.container = container  

    // Map initialize
    this.map = L.map(this.container,{
        zoomControl:false,
        maxZoom:21, 
        minZoom:8,
        center:[50.78898,5.4889],
        zoom:14,
        maxBounds: bounds,
        maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0 // Prevents pushback behaviour at bounds
    });
};
```

finally inside main.js, which might create multiple instances of the mapApp:

```
import {mapApp} from "./app/mapApp.js";

tester = new mapApp('app')
```

for the final line (tester = ...) I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: L.map is not a function`.

I can solve this by importing leaflet again in main.js. But that doesn't seem like the right way to go? It seems like a a hassle that I would have to reload 'child/nested' imports throughout the program chain?

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ridiculousness amount of time I finally solved it.

I must have somewhere loaded a "L" library, confusing me further.

Turns out the minified leaflet (leaflet.js) can not be used for modules. Instead use the leaflet-src.ecm.js file. See also [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862943/what-are-esm-js-files-and-whats-with-the-format-es-in-rollup-js) on more details about the .ecm format.

For other people have this, or a similar issue, I propose to also use the solution in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569996/how-to-use-es6-modules-from-dev-tools-console) and try to load the module straight from the console. Once it works there, you're good to go (unless like me you're confused with a mistakenly loaded library with the same abbreviation)

**TL;DR:** the solution is changing `import * as L from "../lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"` to the correct file, supporting modules: `import * as L from "../lib/leaflet/leaflet-src.esm.js"`